# Wordpress Elementor CSS File not Found

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I'm migrating a Wordpress site that uses Elementor. Code and DB are migrated. But when I inspect the page, there is a 404 error that a css file related to Elementor can't be found.

wp-content/uploads/elementor/css/post-8047.css?ver=1670961064 net::ERR_ABORTED 404

I can't find the file in the directory above, which is odd. I searched the DB also and it doesn't seem to contain a "post-8047". The name must be constructed somewhere.

Any insight on how elementor creates these files and why this css reference is in the head of the site? How can I update it to another reference? I assume there's another version of this post.css file that I could point to? Is there any easy way to adjust?

Comment: Curious if you go to Tools > Regenerate CSS does it create the file? You might need to update a page. https://elementor.com/help/troubleshooting-layout-issues/

Answer (score 4):

If your using elementor and if your page  css is not found go to `elementor->tools` you can find regenerate file. it will regenerate css files it will solved your problem

Comment: that was lifesaver man, thank you

Answer (score 0):

These CSS files are created by elementor for every page. Its name like post-{post-id}.css, in your case its post-8047.css. You can't find this  the database.

This css files contains all styles of that page that we set in elementor settings like color, font etc.

If you can't find the file in folder then it means there is some folder permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me, occured because I changed the local path. I tried using different find-and-replace plugins, but for some reason it didn't work for me.

**Solution**

Elementor stores the font paths in `wp_options` with the `option_name` = `kirki_downloaded_font_files`

Find it and replace the paths in the `option_value`.

Answer (score 0):

If you changed your Wordpress site path on server, please be sure to update `'upload_path'` value in `'wp_options'` table accordingly because Elementor uses this path to store external CSS files while saving/publishing your posts.

In my case it was writing CSS files to old location and site design was not updated. I then noticed 404 errors for resources like `wp-content/uploads/elementor/css/post-{post_id}.css`.

Maybe this will save you some time debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Using an SQL query, I found the template name
SELECT *
FROM wp_posts
WHERE ID = 4556

I went to the template, clicked resave and the CSS file appeared in the Element or folder.

Answer (score -1):

Worked for me to change file permissions to 775 in /wordpress/wp-content/uploads/elementor. Just passed through the same issues.